# Update Switch State

Tags: node-red

I have a flow with where I have a Hue Node -> Switch -> Service Node

Toggling the Switch on and off and I can call the service node and then turn off the light via Home Assistant to Hue just fine. The issue I'm trying to solve is the state of the Switch. I'f I use the Hue app to turn off a light I would like the state of the switch to reflect the state of the light as well so everything is in sync.

However, I'm not sure how to make the switch react to the state of the bulb. I can see the state of the bulb but I'm not sure how to reflect it on the switch.

[image]

Edit: Added Output

```
{
  "on":false,
  "reachable":true,
  "bri":100,
  "xy":[0.4595,0.4105],
  "hsv":[82,56,100],
  "rgb":[202,254,111],
  "hex":"CAFE6F",
  "color":"khaki",
  "mired":369,
  "kelvin":2710
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the output from the debug node so we can see what information the Hue Input node is outputting. (You may want to change it to show the whole message, not just msg.payload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the sample you posted is `msg.payload` then you should be able to use a change node to take the `msg.payload.on` value and move it to `msg.payload`.

[image]

If you then uncheck the "If msg arrives on input, pass through to output: " checkbox this will mean it won't get caught in a loop updating.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works now. Updated the poll time from 10.000 to 1000 and now the switch updates almost at once.

Comment: What if you want the switch to update but not pass it on as why turn it on when it is already on. But if the switch is used then pass it on?